# connecting to a mysql database every second

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm building a chat app that uses a mysql database to store everything from names, messages, ip and other important information. The chat app uses ajax to submit and receive messages from the database. On the receive end, I have it connecting to the database every sec to check for new messages. So my question is... can a mysql database handle let's say 1000+ users connecting to it every second to see if there is new messages? The connection is opened and closed with in a second.

Comment: the question you should be asking is "can my server handle this?" mysql itself couldn't care less. if the hardware is capable of it, then so is mysql.

Comment: You might want to look at using Pusher: http://pusher.com/

Comment: MySQL and a PHP script firing every second isn’t the best way to build a real-time, event-driven chat app. It’s just the wrong technology. You want to look into something like WebSockets.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [redis](http://redis.io/) - it's a better data store for your case. Redis is in memory, so its performance is amazing. You can have Redis connected to MySQL so it fetches the data every once in a while. MySQL is not designed for high random read and writes.

Answer (score 0):

Polling every second is an overkill so you can consider using an memory cache to store undelivered messages. New messages can be pulled from the cache to avoid queries to the database every second from each user!

Comment: Pushing the data via web sockets is a much better approach true real time messaging.